# CakePHP: Sorting multiple HTML tables at once

Tags: php, cakephp, sorting, paginator

I've joined a screenshot showing the multiple tables. I would like the paginator to work with multiple "shown" tables although they are all originating from the same query. Note that the 'Id' column is one of many columns.

```
 var $paginate = array(
            'limit' => 1000);

    function index() {
            $this->Immeuble->recursive = 1;
            $this->Immeuble->contain('Agence');
            $this->set('results', $this->paginate());
            $agences = $this->Immeuble->find('count', array('fields' => 'DISTINCT Agence.Nom'));
            $this->set('agences',$agences);
            $ii = 0;
            $records = $this->Immeuble->find("all",array('fields'=>'Immeuble.id,Immeuble.image,Immeuble.description,Immeuble.start_date,Immeuble.end_date$
            $this->set('records',$records);
            }
```

Here my paginator part in my view:

```
<tr>
                       <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Id','id'); ?></th>
                       <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('description');?></th>
                       <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('start_date');?></th>
                       <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('end_date');?></th>
                       <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('image');?></th>
                       <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ordre');?></th>
                       <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('agence_id');?></th>
                       <th class="actions"><?php __('Actions');?></th>
</tr>
```

[image: Sorting won't work, it'll just order ASC, not DESC.]

Comment: The paginator just doesn't sort out when pressing the anchors. although the little arrows will show up and the url will change.

Comment: Are you using `$results` to show *all* of the data? `$records` will not be paginated/sorted properly because you are not using `Controller::paginate()` to find them (which you can and it will use the same sorting for the request).

Comment: How do I actualy declare another paginator? Won't it just override the parameters I have already set?

Comment: Nope, `$this->paginate()` is just a special find call that uses the paginator parameters. If you use `$records = $this->paginate()` as well, it will paginate that data. You can pass special conditions to it if you want, though from the code you posted it looks like the exact same call as the first one, minus the pagination.

Comment: It works now, thank you Mr Harris. Although when I sort the results using different headers it moves my table order (the last table when sorting IDs ASC will go first on DESC), is there a way to only make results sorted within their table?

Comment: Not out of the box. You'll have to do ajax pagination or write a custom paginator. I added that answer so people can know that this has been solved (when you accept). Glad you got it working!

Comment: I have written a paginator hack, since i'm using CakePHP 1.3.3 and not the latest release, but I would suggest people facing the same issue to get the latest version, it seems to add a lot of features for the paginator and its 'sort' function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paginate multiple times, since it's just a find call. It will reuse the parameters passed by Cake.

```
$records = $this->paginate();
```

You can pass special conditions to this call if you need to.